# Using LinEst in VBA for mulilinear polynomials

Tags: excel, vba

I have been scratching my head over this for a couple of days ad struggling to find an answer.

I have a range of different arrays whcih I am using some VBA code to define and calculate the line of best fit.  I think a 3rd order polynomial (a x^3) should be enough, but if not I want scope to increase this or not.

I would normally tackle this through the LinEst function, however when I apply this in VBA I get a Type Mismatch message and cannot understand why. There is some code to define yval and xval which I have simplified for this.

```
    Dim Aval As Variant
    Dim xval, yval As Range
    Dim star, fin as integer

    star = 3
    fin = 7

    Set yval = Range("AG" & star & ":AG" & fin)
    Set xval = Range("J" & star & ":J" & fin)

    Aval = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(yval, Application.WorksheetFunction.Power(xval, Array(1, 2)))
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Could you include some sample data please (preferably formatted as text)?

Comment: `Aval = Application.LinEst(yval, Application.Power(xval.Value, Array(1, 2)))`

Comment: also should: `Dim xval as Range, yval As Range` and `Dim star as Long, fin as Long`

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Aval As Variant
Dim xval As Range, yval As Range
Dim star As Long, fin As Long

star = 3
fin = 7

With ActiveSheet

    Set yval = .Range("B" & star & ":B" & fin)
    Set xval = .Range("A" & star & ":A" & fin)

    Aval = Application.LinEst(yval, Application.Power(xval, Array(1, 2)))

    .Range("F4:H4") = Aval
End With
```

[image]

Comment: I stand corrected, thank you. Learned a new use for late-binding today...